# Can't login to ubuntu 17.04 GUI after upgrade from 16.04

Tags: nvidia, upgrade, graphics, login

let's start by saying I'm not a Ubuntu Guru, but love the platform and would appreciate assistance. You might direct me to some answers on this problem previously, but none of the answers helped me, specifically.

Here's my problem - I fresh-installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop with the following specifications:

Dell Inspiron 15
intel core i7
NVIDIA graphics (GFORCE)

I noticed that INTEL and NVIDIA drivers clash on Win 10 where the laptop gave a beeping alarm of 6 beeps continuously during start-up. To my surprise Ubuntu 16.04 resolved this issue immediately after the initial installation. 
I was quite happy with 16.04, and when i was offered the upgrade to 17.04, I was quite excited to see the improvements, however, the upgrade has brought back the warning beeps during start-up and now the GUI login screen does not allow me to type in the password. In fact it appears as if the mouse and keyboard freezer up completely. The cursor would blink within the login field, but no entries can be made.

Now I have seen some folks post very similar suggestions where nvidia upgrades must be done, and then the priority must be set between NVIDIA and/or intel graphics, however, this must all be done via Terminal because I can't access the GUI at all. This required me to boot in SafeMode from where I can access the root, but, I'm not an expert and don't want to screw things up.

I'm happy to roll back to 16.04 but don't want to lose any of my data, and in fact 17.04 should work...i Just need a fix for it.

any assistance would be appreciated and sorry if this has been answered before...please point me to the link as i obviously missed it somewhere.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (2016.April release) is an LTS version, and its default upgrade path is to 18.04 which currently is in test (not released), so it should have just bumped you to 16.04.1, 16.04.2... It can be made to upgrade out of the LTS cycle but then it goes to 16.10 before 17.04, 17.10 so your upgrade path implies you've not used supported upgrades (these paths ensure config files work etc).  How did you upgrade; or did you force it?  17.04 (2017.April) is now a couple of days past EOL.

Comment: 16.04 informed me that 17.04 is available as an upgrade...and asked if I want to continue...of course not knowing that 17.04 will be EOL soon!

Comment: Possibly you had edited your `/etc/apt/sources.list`  file and put a 'Yakkety' (meaning 16.10) where a Xenial (16.04) should have been (eg. followed something on a web site about adding a theme/app/.. which used 'yakkety' [Yak] as example), which caused 16.10 code to get into your 16.04 Xenial system, but it can't happen with standard 16.04 code.  17.04 reached EOL on 13 January 2018 (nine months after release) https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2018-January/000227.html  (it won't be patched for Meltdown/Spectre..)

Comment: Having 17.04 you should already have been prompted to release-upgrade to 17.10 which is one option.  Given the 'upgrade' path from 16.04LTS to 17.04 doesn't exist, and yet was offered to you, I'd want to chase down what you did/added/changed to your system to introduce 16.10 code before I trusted it (your system). Rolling back to 16.04 or clean install would be tempting to me. Hopefully someone else has suggestions better than me, but to me your system cries something-is-amiss due upgrade, and I'd be tempted to backup your data & start again.  Easiest if your /home is on a different partition.

Comment: Before you do anything, switch to a text-terminal (eg. ctrl+alt+f4) and login as yourself into a term.  Can you login there?  If yes, the next thing I'd check is `df -hi`  (ie. disk free -human & -inodes mostly out of habit). If space is ~0 (esp. in your /home) GUI can't login anyway, only text terminals can, in which case you have to delete some files, when enough space exists you'll find GUI will login normally. Just a thought.  (-i is for inodes which shouldn't be a problem, but I usually check that too, think blocks or clusters)

Comment: Thanks for the support - after some further "digging" I realized that I have limited "Authority" even after I have logged in with the Root password. The line that appears is root@user-name-laptop:~# and not root@user-name-laptop:~$. Although I can see my files when I'm in the root directory, I cannot see the external flash drive, nor back-up the files. I tried tar cf <name of archive>.tar.gz / home/<username> to back up, but I think due to the authority issues, I wont achieve much. The ultimate objective is to save the data before rolling back to 16.04.

Comment: Why would you have limited 'authority'.   The '#' in the prompt is there as a warning that you have elevated privileges. If you meant something else, sorry I missed it.  Also note ~ will be the /root directory and not your normal-$USER directory

Comment: further to the above error message: backup.tar.gz: Cannot open: Read-only file system tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now. When I login, I also receive the .......: "Read-only file system" message frequently. My data appears to be there, I just can't access it due to the authority issue??

Comment: RO fs??  How are you logged in, via term (ctrl-alt-fn) booting from your HDD or using 'live' media? (eg. install ubuntu). With the fs (filesystem) being RO I'm thinking you're in a recovery mode,   so what is your runlevel (`sudo runlevel`, expecting "N 5"). I would be tempted to just `cp` the [data] files.  FYI: getting your data backed up could be treated as a new question, so if you need help,consider  creating a new question (ie. getting data backed up...)

Comment: yes, remember in 17.04 when the GUI launches I cannot log in. That was the initial discussion, however, I was advise to back-up my files before I do anything else. Once the date is backed-up, I can do a fresh reinstall of 17.10. Due to the fact that the main GUI screen freezes, I have no other option to start the terminal via Recovery mode. When I'm in terminal and type sudo runlevel I get the following message: unable to resolve host  <user-name-laptop>: Connection refused unknown.